# Design pattern to avoid passing unecessary parameters?

Tags: java, design-patterns

In my current project i defined the following interface:

```
public interface CmdExecutor {
    void execute(String[] tokens, OutputStream outputStream, List<ServerWorker> serverWorkers) throws IOException;
}
```

Every `CmdExecutor` needs tokens and outputStream but after the executon of his job, I need to update some information in `List<ServerWorker>`.

There is some design-pattern that can help me to avoid passing to every worker this List?
I've heard about using an "event bus", there is some other option other than this approach?

Thank you

EDIT:

Maybe I expressed myself incorrectly. What I mean was that *all* my `CmdExecutor` needs `String[] tokens` but only *some* of them need to use the `OutputStream outputStream` and `List<ServerWorker> serverWorkers`.
So I find a bad design to hardcode in my interface all the optional parameters only because some implementation needs them.

I tried the factory pattern, but then I had to add all the optional parameters in the factory. In this way the factory can pass the correct parameters to each implementation that needs them.

Is there some pattern that I can use to separate responsabilities of my object?
Something like: observer pattern? listener pattern? events?

I read a lot of this names on internet but I cannot understand which one fits my needs.

Thanks

Comment: `I need to update some information in List<ServerWorker>.` sounds like  Output parameter smell here...  right ? you want to update an input parameter in the execute function() ?

Comment: @CodeScale I think that's the reason why OP is looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [overload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) for a default method which defers to your existing method, passing an empty list as the 3rd argument.

Not sure this fits the description of any specific design pattern.

```
public interface CmdExecutor {
    void execute(String[] tokens, OutputStream outputStream, List<ServerWorker> serverWorkers) throws IOException;

    default void execute(String[] tokens, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        execute(tokens, outputStream, Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Michael, I've just edited my question, can you please give me a hint?